# Python 3 appends random asian chars to file, which encoding is the right one?

Tags: python-3.x, file, file-io, pip, subprocess

I am working on a little script that takes the output of pip freeze and compares it to the old file. Then it appends the new packages at the end of the file. I am developing on Windows 10.

Curiously, no matter which encoding I take this behaviour of appending random asian characters doesn't change. Below you can find the text and I will also paste the output in. I believe the output changes marginally, but I can't be sure.

Thank you.

```
import subprocess, sys, os

reqs = subprocess.check_output([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'freeze']).decode("utf-8") # run pip freeze
reqs = reqs.replace("\n", "").split("\r")   # filter the newline characters

with open("../requirements.txt", "a+") as f:
    old_packages = f.readlines()
    f.write("\n# New Packages: Unidentified")
    for line in reqs:
        if line not in old_packages:
            l = "\n" + line
            f.write(l)
        else:
            continue
```

Output in requirements.txt:

> ┍䁻藕䂦臗銃螁ꊅ䁺闤蒉閅覣覆蒅┍獡楧敲㵦㌽㈮ㄮരਥ獡牴楯㵤㈽㐮㈮┍䌊捡敨潃瑮潲㵬〽ㄮ⸲ശਥ慣档瑥潯獬㴽⸴⸱റਥ散瑲晩㵩㈽㈰⸰⸶〲┍挊慨摲瑥㴽⸳⸰ഴਥ潣潬慲慭㴽⸰⸴ളਥ橄湡潧㴽⸳റਥ橤湡潧挭畯瑮楲獥㴽⸶⸱ലਥ橤湡潧昭汩整㵲㈽㌮〮┍搊慪杮ⵯ畧牡楤湡㴽⸲⸳രਥ橤湡潧敲瑳牦浡睥牯㵫㌽ㄮ⸱റਥ楦敲慢敳愭浤湩㴽⸴⸳രਥ潧杯敬愭楰挭牯㵥ㄽ㈮⸲റਥ潧杯敬愭楰瀭瑹潨⵮汣敩瑮㴽⸱〱〮┍朊潯汧ⵥ畡桴㴽⸱〲ㄮ┍朊潯汧ⵥ畡桴栭瑴汰扩㴲〽〮㐮┍朊潯汧ⵥ汣畯ⵤ潣敲㴽⸱⸴റਥ潧杯敬挭潬摵昭物獥潴敲㴽⸱⸸റਥ潧杯敬挭潬摵猭潴慲敧㴽⸱〳〮┍朊潯汧ⵥ牣㍣挲㴽⸰⸱രਥ潧杯敬爭獥浵扡敬洭摥慩㴽⸰⸷റਥ潧杯敬灡獩挭浯潭⵮牰瑯獯㴽⸱㈵〮┍朊灲楣㵯ㄽ㌮⸱രਥ瑨灴楬㉢㴽⸰㠱ㄮ┍椊湤㵡㈽ㄮരਥ獩牯㵴㐽㌮㈮റਥ慬祺漭橢捥⵴牰硯㵹ㄽ㐮㌮┍䴊牡摫睯㵮㌽㈮㈮┍洊捣扡㵥〽㘮ㄮ┍洊杳慰正㴽⸱⸰രਥ牰瑯扯晵㴽⸳㈱㐮┍瀊慹湳㴱〽㐮㠮┍瀊慹湳ⴱ潭畤敬㵳〽㈮㠮┍瀊汹湩㵴㈽㔮㌮┍瀊汹湩⵴橤湡潧㴽⸲⸳രਥ祰楬瑮瀭畬楧⵮瑵汩㵳〽㘮┍瀊瑹㵺㈽㈰⸰റਥ敲畱獥獴㴽⸲㐲〮┍爊慳㴽⸴ശਥ楳㵸ㄽㄮ⸵രਥ煳灬牡敳㴽⸰⸳റਥ潴汭㴽⸰〱ㄮ┍甊楲整灭慬整㴽⸳⸰റਥ牵汬扩㴳ㄽ㈮⸵〱┍眊慲瑰㴽⸱㈱ㄮ┍

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```py
with open("../requirements.txt", "a+") as f:
```

to

```py
with open("../requirements.txt", "a+", encoding = "utf-8") as f:
```

Comment: Sadly changing the encoding of open() does nothing.